# How should I get generate Class T in inner Class?

Tags: kotlin, generics

```
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType


fun main() {
    val outGeneric = object : OutGeneric<Human>() {}
    outGeneric.innerGeneric.parameter()
}

open class Human(val name: String = "Bob")

abstract class InnerGeneric<in T : Human>() {

    fun parameter() {
        println(javaClass.genericSuperclass.typeName)
        println((javaClass.genericSuperclass as ParameterizedType).actualTypeArguments.toList())
    }

}

abstract class OutGeneric<in T : Human> {

    val innerGeneric = object : InnerGeneric<T>() {}
}
```

I want to get real type in `InnerGeneric` Class. I expect this code will print "Human", but instead it prints "T". How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, given a type, you want to know the type parameter of the type of its `innerGeneric` property. While it may be obvious in the case of `OutGeneric<Human>`, it will not be obvious if the type you are given inherits from `OutGeneric`. You will need to traverse up the inheritance tree to find the answer.

Guava's `TypeToken` (not to be confused with the one in GSON) has a [`resolveType`](https://guava.dev/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html#resolveType-java.lang.reflect.Type-) method that does this.

```
val outGeneric = object : OutGeneric<Human>() {}
// create a type token
val token = TypeToken.of(outGeneric.javaClass) 
// if it is not an anonymous type, write the type out completely
// val token = object: TypeToken<OutGeneric<Human>>() {}

val resolvedToken = token.resolveType(
    // we want to get the return type of the getter of innerGeneric
    OutGeneric<*>::innerGeneric.javaGetter!!.genericReturnType
)
// now token is the type InnerGeneric<Human>

println((resolvedToken.type as ParameterizedType).actualTypeArguments[0])
```